# Display grid and form on sales order view page on click of custom tab

Tags: magento

When we are on sales order view page in admin, there are tabs on left side.. I want to add my own custom tab below that exactly same as Invoices tab.

I am trying to get grid and its form on click of custom tab but not getting it.
Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

To add tab to the order view page you need to create your own module with adminhtml layout xml, add there

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_tab</name>
            <block>module/adminhtml_module_edit_tab_mytab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

so now you need just create block module/adminhtml_module_edit_tab_mytab as usual magento backend grid

Comment: Thank you Pavel for your reply.
I am able to add tab, but the problem is how can I get the grid and form on click of that tab like we are getting while clicking on Invoices tab..

Comment: Okay, thanks Pavel.. I got the grid and form on my custom tab.. but now the problem is that I can't get collection class of my another custom module for grid. Please help me to figure this out.